# WPF TabHeader Foreground color getting reverted after TabControl is hidden and then shown

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I am working on a WPF application which has a styled TabControl.
We have a requirement where we need to show/hide the TabControl as per user selection. For this I set the Visibility of TabControl to Collapsed and then to Visible again when required.

The problem I am facing is that when I hide the TabControl and show it again the text in the TabHeader reverts back to the original colour.
Further I have come to notice that styles/colors of all the texts in the TabHeaders seems to reset.

Here is the Style for TabControl and TabHeader:

```
<Style x:Key="g_TabControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,4,4,4"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabControlNormalBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabControlPaneTopNormalBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" Grid.Column="0" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="0,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
                        <Border x:Name="ContentPanel" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" Grid.Column="0" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="0,0,2,2"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabControlPaneBottomNormalBackground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="2,2,-1,2"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabControlPaneLeftNormalBackground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="-1,2,2,2"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabControlPaneRightNormalBackground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

<Style x:Key="g_TabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,2,12,2"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabControlNormalBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItemNormalBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="true" MinWidth="90" MaxWidth="190">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="border1">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.2"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#8CFFFFFF"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,1,0">
                            <Grid x:Name="Transform">
                                <Border x:Name="border1" Background="White"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="contentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource g_EmptyFocusVisualStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItemHotBackground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItemSelectedBackground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#8CFFFFFF"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="Transform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" ScaleX="1"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="Transform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="Transform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItemDisabledBackground}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabItemDisabledBorderBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Top"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-2,-1"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-1,-2"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,-2,-2,-2"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Other resources are as:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabControlNormalBorderBrush" Color="#919B9C"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabItemNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFBDBEDE" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabItemHotBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFBDBEDE" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemSelectedBackground" Color="#FFFCFCFE"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemDisabledBackground" Color="#FFF5F4EA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemDisabledBorderBrush" Color="#FFC9C7BA"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabControlPaneTopNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFCFCFE" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFF4F3EE" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabControlPaneBottomNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFCFCFE" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFF4F3EE" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabControlPaneLeftNormalBackground" EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFCFCFE" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFF4F3EE" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabControlPaneRightNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="1,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFCFCFE" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFF4F3EE" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

I have tried giving/setting different colours(other than white) to the texts and then I came to notice that everything works as expected till the TabControl is hidden, but then all texts revert back to white as soon as the TabControl is hidden and then re-shown.

Does anyone know what could cause this sort of behaviour or what could be wrong with the above XAML?